# c++ Behavioral tree patterns and calling members without semicolons or pointer references

Tags: c++, pointers, tree

I have a quick question about this type of implementation calling in a behavioral tree pattern . From what I can see the first line they call the pointer to an object "builder" but every subsequent line after it they omit calling the pointer object "builder". They also omit  the ";" semicolon

a: what type of pattern is this and where can I find a reference to calling members on a pointer like this

```
BT::BehaviorTree* Bt=Builder
    ->ActiveSelector()
        ->Sequence()
            ->Condition(BT::EConditionMode::IsSeeEnemy,false)
                 ->Back()       
            ->ActiveSelector()
                 -> Sequence()
                      ->Condition(BT::EConditionMode::IsHealthLow,false)
                           ->Back()
                      ->Action(BT::EActionMode::Runaway)
                            ->Back()
                      ->Back()
                ->Parallel(BT::EPolicy::RequireAll, BT::EPolicy::RequireOne)
                      ->Condition(BT::EConditionMode::IsEnemyDead,true)
                            ->Back()
                      ->Action(BT::EActionMode::Attack)
                            ->Back()
                      ->Back()
               ->Back()
            ->Back()
    ->Action(BT::EActionMode::Patrol)
->End();
```

The Definition of the class looks like this

```
class BehaviorTreeBuilder
{
public:
    BehaviorTreeBuilder() { }
    ~BehaviorTreeBuilder() { }
    BehaviorTreeBuilder* Sequence();
    BehaviorTreeBuilder* Action(EActionMode ActionModes);
    BehaviorTreeBuilder* Condition(EConditionMode ConditionMode, bool IsNegation);
    BehaviorTreeBuilder* Selector();
    BehaviorTreeBuilder* Repeat(int RepeatNum);
    BehaviorTreeBuilder* ActiveSelector();
    BehaviorTreeBuilder* Filter();
    BehaviorTreeBuilder* Parallel(EPolicy InSucess, EPolicy InFailure);
    BehaviorTreeBuilder* Monitor(EPolicy InSucess, EPolicy InFailure);
    BehaviorTreeBuilder* Back();
    BehaviorTree* End();
}
```

The main question I have is that the I understand that they creating an object pointer and adding methods to the pointer .

but what I dont understand is when they call the tree builder that each new line omits the pointer name and gets away with following e.g

```
...= Builder 
-> functionA()
-> functionB()
-> functionA()
-> functionC();
```

Is this perhaps some kind of a lambda expression or  stack or queue pattern ? .
What's the patterns name and where can I find a reference to it as all the books I've read makes no reference to doing things like this .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each function returns the pointer, which can then be used by the next `->`.

Answer (score 1):

> The implementation of the class

This is not a class implementation, this is a class definition.

The possible class member function implementation:

```
BehaviorTreeBuilder* BehaviorTreeBuilder::Sequence() {
  // Do stuff
  return this;
}
```

All the magic is in `return this`.

```
= Builder 
-> functionA()
-> functionB();
```

It's same as

```
= (Builder 
-> functionA())
-> functionB();
```

If a function returns a pointer, you can deal with a result as with a pointer.

Comment: I agree its definition Ill change accordingly but the question remains on calling the methods -> func -> func ->

Ahh cool so I call other classes the same way .  

you dont have another reference online or book as to  calling things like this . I would like to brush up some skills in it

Comment: @JonoJames `Builder` is a pointer, you can do `Builder->` with a pointer. `Builder->functionA()` is a pointer, you can do `Builder->functionA()->` with a pointer.

Comment: Maybe you are confused by new lines. C++ is not a scripting language. An expression continues until ; is met, new lines and other whitespaces inside expressions are ignored.

Comment: Well I learned somthing new ... Ahaaa Moment